# Error : curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl

I have a R code deployed on AWS server to fetch twitter data which is basically creating an API.

I want to fetch the data on local system using this API which is fetching the data using the function running on aws server.

I'm using this command :

$curl "http://127.0.0.1 ip-**public ip**:8000/meaning?woeid=23424848&n=1"

But i'm getting the error below :

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ip-**public ip**